# Space in date in ksh

Tags: unix, ksh

My requirement is, to assign value for a Parameter in Informatica. (I'm assigning timestamp to a Parameter)

Here I need to give space in between Date & Time for a timestamp.

I need to like print this `03/02/2016 08:48:40.000000` I have tried

```
TIMESTAMP=`date +%m/%d/%Y %H:%S:%M`
```

But it is getting error.

```
Field descriptor must begin with a + (plus sign).
```

Also I need to this print like `$$LAST_RUN_TIME=03/02/2016 08:48:40.000000`

I tried `echo "$$LAST_RUN_TIME=$TIMESTAMP"` But the `$$`is retrieving some value, So it printing like this `61210934LAST_RUN_TIME=03/02/2016 08:48:40.000000`

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: Have you tried to surround double quotes to the format? TIMESTAMP=`date "+%m/%d/%Y %H:%S:%M"`

Comment: Nice. I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The space in the argument to `date` must be quoted.  There are three ways to do this:

1. Use a backslash:

   ```sh
   TIMESTAMP=`date +%m/%d/%Y\ %H:%S:%M`
   ```

   This is probably the easiest for your example, but can get unwieldy if lots of quoting is needed.
2. Use single quotes:

   ```sh
   TIMESTAMP=`date '+%m/%d/%Y %H:%S:%M'`
   TIMESTAMP=`date +'%m/%d/%Y %H:%S:%M'`
   ```

   This is good when you have literal arguments.
3. Use double quotes:

   ```sh
   TIMESTAMP=`date "+%m/%d/%Y %H:%S:%M"`
   ```

   This is good when you have parameters that you need expanding:

   ```sh
   format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%S:%M'
   TIMESTAMP=`date "+$format"`
   ```

All of these can use `$(`...`)` instead of backquotes, which you may (or may not) find more readable:

```sh
TIMESTAMP=$(date +%m/%d/%Y\ %H:%S:%M)

TIMESTAMP=$(date '+%m/%d/%Y %H:%S:%M')
TIMESTAMP=$(date +'%m/%d/%Y %H:%S:%M')

TIMESTAMP=$(date "+%m/%d/%Y %H:%S:%M")

format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%S:%M'
TIMESTAMP=$(date "+$format")
```

---

By the way - do you really want seconds before minutes?  If not, then you can use `%T` in place of `%H:%M:%S`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to surround the format with double quotes.

```
TIMESTAMP=$(
    date "+%m/%d/%Y %H:%S:%M"
)

echo $TIMESTAMP
03/03/2016 08:04:49
```

Comment: @henk-langeveld Thank you. Doble-click in os x terminal does not include the $-sign.